# Alternative implementation for JSONObject.java

Tags: java, json, talend

I'm using Talend DI java code as part of oVirt DWH that runs on both Fedora and CentOS.

[JSONObject.java](https://github.com/Talend/tcommon-studio-se/blob/master/main/plugins/org.talend.librariesmanager/resources/java/routines/system/JSONObject.java) has a software license which is not okay for Fedora.

Is JSONObject.java can be replaced with an alternative implementation?
Perhaps a different library such as jackson 2.9 library can be implemented instead?

The code calls the JSONObject in [class ResumeUtil](https://github.com/Talend/tcommon-studio-se/blob/master/main/plugins/org.talend.librariesmanager/resources/java/routines/system/ResumeUtil.java#L358).

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is asking for a software recommendation, and that is off-topic.  However, the Fedora licensing requirements only cover software that is proposed to be delivered as official Fedora packages.  There is no reason why you can't *use* software with "bad licenses" on Fedora.  Or indeed package the software as RPMs (etc) for use on Fedora platforms.

Comment: And to answer your question.  There is no technical reason why you couldn't modify talend software to use a different JSON library.  But you *would* need to *modify* the talend code to do this.  JSON libraries are not "drop in" interchangeable.

Comment: There's a JIRA for this: https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-44440

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the quick responses!

Stephen, unfortunately the JSON License has been rejected by our legal team, so we need to provide an alternative implementation.
Yes I will need to change the code, do you know any other library besides JSON that can fit the JSONObject  implementation in [class ResumeUtil] (https://github.com/Talend/tcommon-studio-se/blob/master/main/plugins/org.talend.librariesmanager/resources/java/routines/system/ResumeUtil.java#L358) ?


Balazs, the JIRA created by a co-worker, but it does not look like they are going to fix it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.